# How to find out the exact conflicts with NSLayoutConstraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to position my *40x40 Logo* on top of the screen, *20pt* from the top, and lastly horizontally aligned with the parent view.

```
var views = ["tableView":self.tableView!,"logoImageView":logoImageView,"view":self.view]

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[logoImageView(40)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[logoImageView(40)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[logoImageView]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))        

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view][logoImageView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views));
```

But this is the error I got in the debugger/console.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa78487e8f0 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7fa784b29350]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa784886f70 V:[UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fa784b29350]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa78488caa0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa784886f70 V:[UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fa784b29350]>
```

Would be great if someone can help explain where's the issue and what's the proper way to do `NSLayoutFormatOptions`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with these two constraints:

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[logoImageView]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))        
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view][logoImageView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views));
```

The first says that the top of `logoImageView` should be 20 points from the top of its superview. The second says that the top of `logoImageView` should be 0 points from the bottom of `view`.

The problem is that `view` is the superview of `logoImageView`. You can tell because the superview (`|`) in this constraint:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa78487e8f0 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7fa784b29350]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0 )>",
```

is the same as the adjacent view in this constraint:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa784886f70 V:[UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fa784b29350]>",
```

So, the two constraints together require that `view` be 20 points tall. However, the table view is imposing a height of 667 points for that view, as shown with this constraint:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa78488caa0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fa78373b8e0(667)]>"
```

Hence the conflict.

I suspect the problem is that you have added `logoImageView` to the wrong view or you meant to list some other view in the `V:[view][logoImageView]` visual format string.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this simply way:

1. When you notice the error log, press `Pause` to start the `lldb`debug session
2. In console type:
   `expr [(UIImageView *)0x7fa784b29350 setHidden: YES];`

You will notice that the view

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa78487e8f0 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7fa784b29350]>
```

will disappear, and so you will know which it is

Comment: instead of `setHidden:YES` I would suggest `setBackgroundColor:[UIColor magentaColor]`. Makes the view a bit more obvious than hiding it.